# Trying to install new gfx card, it's plugged in but I get "No Signal" when turning on monitor

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

I just bought a Radeon HD 6770 graphics card.  It is plugged into the only graphics card connector on my motherboard.  I have it connected to the power supply (using a 6-pin red connector that says "PCI-E" on it, I think that's the right connector?  Mine has a 6-pin and a separate 2-pin connector, but the gfx card only has one 6-pin connector).

I power on the computer, all the fans spin, but I get "No Signal" to the monitor; the monitor works on another PC.  Am I connecting something wrong (maybe using the wrong 6-pin)?  I literally JUST opened the graphics card box; it was brand new from TigerDirect.  All of the below parts are around 2 months old or newer.

Specs:

- Motherboard: ASUS M5A97 R2.0
- GFX Card: Radeon HD 6770
- RAM: 8GB (Corsair DDR3)
- CPU: AMD Phenom II 965 Black Edition
- Monitor: Acer P215H
- PSU: Thermaltake TR2 700W

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as for the love of me I can't seem to get some simple upgrades working and I've been at it for 3 months now and spent close to $1000 on various parts that don't work.  I've had to replace a power supply, a motherboard, and another graphics card because the pieces would not work together, and I have no idea why something seemingly so simple is causing me such grief.

EDIT: This "No Signal" issue has been going on for several months now with a variety of components.  I replaced a power supply and motherboard and Sapphire Radeon HD 7850 that I was told were all bad/fried because the monitor never detected the graphics card.  Now with a brand new out of the box card I'm still getting that same error so there must be something I am doing wrong (I highly doubt that two different PSUs and gfx cards could both be bad immediately).  The only things I haven't swapped out and replaced are the DVD-RW, the hard drive and the case itself (it's a generic black iBuyPower case as the original PC was one of those), everything else has been replaced at least once and still I get this "No Signal" error.

Comment: Nitpick detail: "It's plugged into the only graphics card connector on my motherboard."  No it is not. Googling shows that the Asus M5A97 R2.0 has 4 PCIe connectors. These can be used for general purpose PCIe cards (including but not limited to graphics cards). Two are x1 (the small ones, two are x16, one coloured blue, one black).

Comment: As to trying to find out what is wrong, lets start with the obvious questions:
1 ) Is the monitor cable plugged in at both ends? (Before you ask: Yes, some people do forget that). 
2) Is the monitor set to use the right connection? E.g If the monitor has both DVI and VGA inputs, VGA is selected and you just connected a DVI cable then you will also get that no signal message.
3) It is a correct and working cable? (Could be subtle here. E.g. a single link DVI cable on a monitor which dual-link DVI. With only "Monitor: Acer 21 inch" we can not check that.

Comment: As to the 6/8 pin connector. These usually often come as a 6+2 set, where you can pry the extra 2 pins loose. (some cards use the 6 pin(s) connectors, some the 8 pins. So this is the easiest way for PSU manufacturers).

Comment: *spent close to $1000 on various parts that don't work* Various AMD parts, it seems. There's a reason I buy Intel + NVIDIA.

Comment: Yes, monitor is plugged in.  Monitor is DVI only, and works fine on another computer (the one I am typing this reply on).  Monitor is Acer P215H. The gfx card uses 6 pins and 6 pins are what I have plugged in; no luck.  Been having that "no signal" error for 3+ months now and replaced a power supply, motherboard, and other gfx card (a HD 7850 that I was told was defective since it too got No Signal after being plugged in) all in vain.  As to Intel vs. AMD I originally had an AMD mobo (that I replaced) and by the time I replaced it I had already spent money on a new AMD processor.

Comment: 1) Parts are often DOA.  2) "I have no idea why something seemingly so simple is causing me such grief": there's a reason people buy pre-assembled computers. 3) Have you tried the graphics card in another computer?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the other computer I have has too weak of a power supply to run either graphics card (when I originally bought the HD 7850 I tried to run it on a 300W power supply.  That was the original start of the "No Signal" trouble).  I have a Tiger Direct story nearby that I think I'm going to bring it to in order to let them look at it, since they're more qualified than I am.

Comment: Also I understand parts are often DOA, but two components in a row?  that seems a bit unlikely unless I have REALLY bad luck.

Comment: Aye. Twice is quite unlikely. Say one in 20 is broken (and that seems very high), then the chance to get two broken items in a row would be one in four hundred. Not quite lotto numbers, but heading in the right direction.

Comment: @Hennes With AMD it's frequently one in one that is broken. But your original assessment that "twice is quite unlikely" is still correct, even when dealing with AMD. Simply because people then go and buy Intel or NVIDIA components, avoiding the chance of getting a dud the second time.

Comment: You might just have had bad luck. I have build computer for myself and friends for 2 decades now. Failed graphical card total: 0 (Cards were about evenly split between ATI/AMD-baed, Nvidia-baed and Matrox).